# Django base url: example.com

Tags: django, url-routing

How do I catch the following two urls in my urls.py?

```
example.com
example.com/
```

Right now I'm doing:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlprefix = 'websites.app'
urlpatterns = patterns(urlprefix,
        (r'index/$', 'public.views.index'), # landing page
        )
```

If I add:

```
        (r'$', 'public.views.index'), # landing page
```

as a catch-all, then it gets all rules. I just want it to go to index when there's a trailing slash or nothing past the base url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(r'^$', 'public.views.index'), # landing page`

and then set `APPEND_SLASH` true in [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash).